# If $A_n$ are independent events, how to prove that $A_n\cup A_{n+1}$ and $A_{n+2}\cup A_{n+3}$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of independent events.

Intuitively, it is clear that $A_n\cup A_{n+1}$ and  $A_{n+2}\cup A_{n+3}$ should be independent.

I suppose one can prove it using the inclusion exclusion principle, but that leads to messy calculations of various products, which is quite frustrating.

How can this be proven in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considered $\mathcal{F}_n =\sigma(\{A_n\})$ for $n\ge 1$. If $$A_1, A_2,\dots $$ are independent then $$\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2,\dots$$ are independent.

It is known that 
$$\sigma(\mathcal{F}_1, \mathcal{F}_2), \sigma(\mathcal{F}_3,\mathcal{F}_4),\dots $$ are independent. This is sufficient since that $A_n\cup A_{n+1}\in \sigma( \mathcal{F}_n,\mathcal{F}_{n+1})$.

Comment: Review https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665671/238946