# union of independent events

Tags: probability-theory

Assume we have a set of independent events $\{A_{i} | i \in \bigcup_{j\in J} I(j) \}$, where $I$ and $J$  are finite and not empty sets. My question is regarding the union of events, is it also independent? I mean is these events that are composed of the union of the individual events independent

$\{\bigcup_{i\in I(j)}A_{i} | j \in J \}$

For example, $J = \{0,1\}$, $I = (\lambda i.\ if\ i = 0\  then\ \{0,1,2\}\ else\ \{3,4\})  $

so, $\{A_{i} | i \in \bigcup_{j\in J} I(j) \} = \{A_{i} | i \in \{0,1,2,3,4\} \}$  are independent

Now, are the following events independent as well?

$\{\bigcup_{i\in I(j)}A_{i} | j \in J \} = \{\bigcup_{i\in \{0,1,2\}} A_{i}\ ,\  \bigcup_{i \in \{3,4\}} A_{i} \}$

If they are independent, how can I prove it for the general case (not just for the example) without using the inclusion-exclusion principle?

For example, if I have three independent events $A,B$ and $C$ then using some set theory operations and the inclusion-exclusion principle

$Pr ((A\cup B) \cap C)$ = $Pr (A\cup B) \times Pr(C)$

but I need to prove the above for any sets $I$ and $J$ without using the inclusion-exclusion principle

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that $\{I(j)\mid j\in J\}$ denotes a partition of $I$ so that the sets $I(j)$ are disjoint.

For $j\in J$ let $\mathcal A_j:=\sigma(\{A_i\mid i\in I(j)\})$ i.e. the $\sigma$-algebra generated by  the events $A_i$ with $i\in I(j)$.

Then here we are dealing with independent $\sigma$-algebras.

To get more sight on this you could define random variables of the form $X_j=\sum_{i\in I(j)}c_i\mathbf1_{A_i}$ where the $c_i$ are distinct.

It is evident that the $X_j$ are independent and that $\mathcal A_j=\sigma(X_j)$.

Now observe that r.v. $\mathbf1_{\bigcup_{i\in I(j)}A_i}$ is $\mathcal A_j$-measurable for every $j$, so these functions are independent.

That means exactly that the events $\bigcup_{i\in I(j)}A_i$ are independent.

Comment: can we prove it without going through random variables?

Comment: Needed is actually a proof that sigma-algebra's like the $\mathcal A_j$ are independent. In principle this can be done without the use of random variables.

Comment: Could you please refer me to a book that lists all the details about this proof? and independent sigma algebras? and also, assuming that I proved that the sigma algebras are independent, how can I prove that the union is also independent ?

Comment: The statement that  $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are independent is actually the same statement that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ for every $A\in\mathcal A$ and every $B\in\mathcal B$. This can immediately be applied on countable unions of elements of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$. The theorem you need is that independence of generators of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ is enough for independence of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ itself. Sorry, but I have no book reference for that (I am autodidactic and have no familiarity with books).

Comment: Maybe answers on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665671/75923) can help if you take for $\mathcal A_i$ the sigma algebra generated by event $A_i$.

Comment: I will look at the answers of the question in the link that you mentioned. Thank you